# Remote script execution using Net::SSH::Expect in perl

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to execute remote script using following command by connecting to one of the server using `Net::SSH::Expect` perl module.

```
$ssh->exec("python test.py");
```

Script is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host => 'hostip', #deb-2-scripting ip
    user => 'user',
    password => 'password',
    raw_pty => 1
);

..
..
$result = $ssh->exec("python test.py");
..
..
$ssh->close();
```

Actually this remote script `(test.py)` is taking longer than expected to execute (Because its having so many checks inside).

1. Is there any way that I can just fire this script `(test.py)` and continue with my perl script execution (I dont want to wait till test.py execution completion). 
   OR
2. How can I wait till the test.py execution completion without giving timeout.
   Since I could see by giving `$ssh->exec("python test.py", 10);` this waits for 10 seconds so that `test.py` execution gets succeeded.

Comment: Why not just run the command in the background with the shell: `$ssh->exec("python test.py &");` ? See [Run a Unix process in the background](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnz)

Comment: Good idea @hakon. So in this case test.py will execute from background and the Perl script will not bother about the test.py executed successfully or not and continues it's flow. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the command handed to `$ssh->exec("command")` is run by the shell on the server, you can run the Python command in the background like you would do for a normal shell command, by including an & (an ampersand) at the end of the command:

```
$ssh->exec("python test.py &");
```

This will cause `exec()` to return immediately, while the python command is running as a background process on the server.

**Edit**:

It seems like `$ssh->exec($cmd, $timeout)` is not able to tell exactly when the `$cmd` finished. I wonder if this is a bug? It always waits `$timeout` seconds, even if the command finishes before that. A workaround is use `$ssh->send()` combined with `$ssh->waitfor()` like this:

```
$str = '__DONE__';
$ssh->send("python test.py; echo $str");
my $result = $ssh->waitfor($str, undef);  #<-- undef means wait for ever or 
                                          # until $str is matched.
```

Comment: So in order to see if test.py is executed successfully or not what should I do (In my question (2)) ? As of now I am giving timeout inside exec command. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: I think if you set timeout to `undef` it will wait forever (i.e. until the command finishes). You could use this to fork a new process that waits for the python script, while the parent process continues working

Comment: In this case yes, its waiting forever and never comes back to perl script.

Comment: I thought it could be because the python script had turned on output buffering, but I ran small test now with `python -u`, and it still does not work.. strange. I will have to look closer into this issue

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hakon. But I don't wish to give timeout inside exec command.

Comment: You are welcome. See my updated answer for an approach

Comment: Yep that is useful. So without getting the $str its hard to assume whether the remote script executed or not right.

Comment: Yes, but it *should* not be hard. I think it is a bug. The timeout parameter to `exec()` should work similarly to `waitfor()`. I will see if I can find out more..

Comment: I found a better workaround, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Hakon. But if you print ```$result``` its giving a value 1 if you found the string. Instead of that can I print whatever value its been returned from remote script?

Comment: Hi! The output should be available by calling `$ssh->before()`